# Eclipse Error in Tomcat7 Server

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have configured Tomcat 7 with Eclipse Helios 1.3.2 on port number 8080. Tomcat Service and everything is installed.

When I am starting the server from Eclipse, it does some process and shows the status as STARTED. But when I try to hit `http://localhost:8080`, it says *The requested resource (/) is not available.* i.e. in fact server is not started in reality.

However, when I am starting the server from Windows Explorer by running Tomcat7.exe or Tomcat7w.exe, it starts well and I am able to see Apache Home page by referring to `http://localhost:8080`.

Below is the server start up log.

```
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;O:\ora1106w\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin;;C:\Program Files\WinMerge;C:\Users\KNIRAV\Downloads\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5674 ms
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:18 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [126] milliseconds.
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 02, 2012 1:20:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1788 ms
```

Can I have some solution to this please?

Comment: Note that deploy.wsdd is specific to Axis 1.x and is not used in Axis2. You need to clarify your question and clearly indicate if you want to create an Axis 1.x or Axis2 service.

Comment: @AndreasVeithen - I want to create on Axis2 Only. My question is how to get rid of the error? Error screen capture link is pasted.

Comment: That error message is from the Axis 1.x tooling. If you want to use Axis2, then it doesn't make any sense to debug that error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. When you start Tomcat from Eclipse a root application is not deployed. Only the projects that you deploy through the server view are available.

Have you tried to deploy a project on the server?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! I deployed one of the projects and it worked.

Comment: I deployed one of the very basic webservices project. Here, I am trying to generate webservice from the java class. It throws below error `IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP (400)Bad Request
`. I am using Axis2. Please guide, what could be the error?

Comment: I do not have much experience with Axis2 + Eclipse, sorry. Maybe this eclipse plugin can help you: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html